# EMI by cutting a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I know that one can explain motional emf by considering a free electron in the conductor and finding the force it experiences in the magnetic field. but I have read some explanations which involve 'cutting' of magnetic flux. The method seems correct, but I am unable to understand it entirely.

If the velocity of the rod is perpendicular to the rod, the rod cuts the magnetic field lines (assuming they exist as lines), but if velocity is parallel to the length, it doesn't do so!

I would like to know why exactly it is able to 'cut' the field, or more precisely, what it does when it cuts the field.

(The Lorentz force on point charge explanation is easier, but this is given in the book that I follow, just so you know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine there is a stream of water and you are moving a stick in it. When you are moving the stick parallel to the flow of water you are actually not cutting it. If you are moving the stick perpendicular to the flow of water you are cutting it " the most". If you move the stick at an another angle other than  purely parallel or perpendicular angle there will always be perpendicular and parallel component of the motion with respect to the flow of the stream.

The magnitude of the induced emf also depends upon the angle at which the conductor cuts the magnetic field lines.
Where direction of the magnetic field lines from north to south corresponds to the flow of water. And  the conductor corresponds to your stick.